# reading unicode data from a file

Tags: java

Default encoding is ISO-8859-1

```
    BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("file having unicode characters"),"UTF-8"));
    String strTemp = bis.readLine();// on debugging strTemp is having actual unicode data


    System.out.println(strTemp);// uses default encoding which is ISO-8859-1,So not printing   ///actual data


   PrintStream psTemp = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
   psTemp.println(strTemp);// here i am giving encoding as UTF-8,still not printing unicode data.
```

Even if i am giving encoding as UTF-8 in PrintStream constructor i am not able to print unicode data, if i change default encoding from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8, it works. Why this is so?

Answer (score 0):

> if i change default encoding from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8, it works. Why this is so?

I expect that this works because it is telling your console / shell / whatever is displaying the characters to expect UTF-8 characters.  If the default behaviour is to expect ISO-8859-1, then sending it UTF-8 is not going to work.

Comment: means writing PrintStream psTemp = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8"); and giving encoding as UTF-8 won't help?

Comment: It won't help/work if the console (or whatever) expects your application to be outputting ISO-8859-1 ... which it is likely to expect if ISO-8859-1 is the platform's default encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Are you printing on eclipse console ? or in the shell ? Try to print to a file and check the result.

For example, windows shell is limited to "cp850" charset. The problem might be caused by the OS shell, not the JVM.

Comment: Its printing properly in a file